# Using $expand query in Azure Mobile Services Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

Is it possible to use the `$expand=<table>` query in the Azure Mobile Services javascript SDK? I am interested in returning some of the related objects in a single query as [explained here](http://zimmergren.net/technical/extending-windows-azure-mobile-services-queries-to-include-relational-data-and-optional-metadata). I guess another solution is to query both tables and join them manually in my javascript code, but this feels kinda stupid when there is a `$expand` option for all the other SDKs.

I am using MobileServices.Web-1.2.5.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javascript SDK equivalent way to add a client-side filter is the [MobileServiceClient withFilter](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-how-to-use-client-library/#customizing) function:

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://your-app-url', 'your-key')
           .withFilter(function (request, next, callback) {
           if (request.url.indexOf("/tables/todolist") >= 0 && request.url.indexOf("$expand") === -1) {
               request.url = request.url + (request.url.indexOf("?") === -1) ? "?" : "&";
               request.url = request.url + "$expand=name";
           }
           next(request, callback);
        });
```

See also Carlos Figueira's [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2014/02/24/using-service-filters-with-the-mobile-services-javascript-sdk.aspx), which goes into much more detail than the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Do you know if it possible to expand more than one related table? I tried writing ``request.url = request.url + "$expand=table1&$expand=table2"`` but that did not work.

Comment: comma separate the properties e.g. `$expand=table1,table2`